# error ActivityManager: PID: 24243

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I have to errors when I use my application.

First:

> JS: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode()
>   to enable the production mode.
>
> ActivityManager: PID: 24243
>
> ActivityManager:   106% 24243/org.nativescript.project:
>   95% user + 11% kernel / faults: 27378 minor 1 major
>
> ActivityManager:   11% 24243/org.nativescript.project:
>   9.2% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 364 minor 1 major

Second:
Second error that is in [image: her]

show me when I use a menu. Menu is very slowly, when I used very often show me this error :(

I tried this menu:

```
<GridLayout rows="*,60">
    <StackLayout row="1" orientation="horizontal" backgroundColor="#eae8e8" class="foot">
        <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/home/events']" width="25%" textAlignment="left">
            <img src="~/assets/images/info.png" width="20" height="20" stretch="aspectFit" />
            <Label>
                <FormattedString color="#EE6E73">
                    <Span text="Events"></Span>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/home/fp']" width="25%" textAlignment="left">
            <img src="~/assets/images/home.png" width="20" height="20" stretch="aspectFit" />
            <Label>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Home"></Span>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/home/image']" width="25%" textAlignment="left">
            <img src="~/assets/images/paketa.png" width="30" height="20" stretch="aspectFit" />
            <Label>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Images"></Span>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/home/settings']" width="25%" textAlignment="left">
            <img src="~/assets/images/settings.png" width="20" height="20" stretch="aspectFit" />
            <Label>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span text="Settings"></Span>
                </FormattedString>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Where does `img` tag comes from? In NativeScript it's `Image`. In Angular, you can't use self-closing tags so you would have to end it with `</Image>` instead of `/>` Does this code even works?

Comment: Yes this code works, and image show correctly

Comment: your `img` tags need to look like the following: `<Image src="~/assets/images/info.png" width="20" height="20" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>`

Comment: I change and I tried again. Error 2 show again

Comment: why do you use the `FormattedString` and `Span` tags if you dont actually make use of them?

Comment: I tried like this:    `<StackLayout [nsRouterLink]="['/home/settings']" width="25%" textAlignment="left"><Image src="~/assets/images/settings.png" width="20" height="20" stretch="aspectFit"></Image>  <Label  text="Settings"> </Label>     </StackLayout>` the error show agian when I used very often

Comment: I assume that the error might not be in the templates, but in the TypeScript behind it. Can you isolate the problem in the [NativeScript Playground](https://play.nativescript.org) and share it here.

Comment: This template is in MainComponent, in Typescript have nothing. `selector: "menubar-app",` I put in her `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
<menubar-app></menubar-app>`